# How to connect to Tridion using core service from client machine

Tags: tridion

I am working on creating component using the Core Service to connect to Tridion 2011 SP1. I wrote the code in the server machine to create a component through the Core Service, and it worked well. The code was executed from server machine.

Now I want to execute same code from client machine.

I came to know that we can execute the code from Client machine as well.

Can any one share what all the configuration that I need to do in the client machine to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

CoreService is a WCF webservice and as with any webservice there's no any difference as to where you connect to it from, provided you can connect and authenticate. All you need to do is to change app.config of your client to point to proper server, or change it in the code if you have it hardcoded. Also, you might need to add authentication to your client code in case you don't want to use default credentials.

In general, CoreService is following WCF and if you are having any problems with it - you can troubleshoot it as any other WCF service. There are plenty of answers on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this: http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/core-service-client-sample-code.html

It describes several ways of connecting to the Core Service.